# How to add columns based on original column with string pattern?

Tags: python, pandas

**df**

```
         f
0   l2y_q1_eps_gg
1   l2y_q2_eps_gg
2   l2y_q3_eps_gg
3   l2y_q4_eps_gg
4   l1y_q1_eps_gg
```

**Goal**

```
         f          fr_date
0   l2y_q1_eps_gg   20190331
1   l2y_q2_eps_gg   20190630
2   l2y_q3_eps_gg   20190930
3   l2y_q4_eps_gg   20191231
4   l1y_q1_eps_gg   20200331
5   cy_q1_eps_gg    20210331
```

The value of `fr_date` column is the last day of each year of each quarter and the rule is like below and the type of fr_date is int :

- l2y:2019
- l1y:2020
- cy:2021
- q1-q4: the last day of each quarter

Notice:

- the start pattern of `f` column is `l2y/l1y/cy`+ `q1/q2/q3/q4`.
- If the current year changes, the rule will change. For example ,if current year is 2022, then l2y→2020, l1y→2021, cy→2022.

Comment: kindly show your code and where it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for two things: a translation function, and how to apply this function to a column of a pandas Dataframe to get a new column.

**Translation function**

There are several ways to do it, but here is one :

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Last days of quarters are always the same
last_quarter_days = {"q1": "0331", "q2": "0630", "q3": "0930", "q4": "1231"}

def translate_date(string):
    # Extract year and quarter for the full string
    year_str, quarter_str, _, _, = string.split("_")
    # Compute year automatically
    current_year = datetime.today().year
    if year_str == "cy":
        year = current_year
    else:
        # This is a dumb extractor, you could do a pattern search
        # and raise an exception if the string is not correct
        sub = int(year_str[1])
        year = current_year - sub
    # Translate the quarter string thanks to the translation table
    day = last_quarter_days[quarter_str]
    # return the date as an integer (but maybe you want a string?)
    return int("{year}{day}".format(year=year, day=day))
```

Which gives:

```py
>>> translate_date("cy_q1_eps_gg")                    
20210331
```

**How to apply this to your Dataframe**

With the [map method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map) of pandas.

```py
df["fr_date"] = df["f"].map(translate_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QuarterEnd` offset to compute date for end of each quarter:

```
current_year = pd.datetime.now().year

mapping = {"l2y": current_year - 2, "l1y": current_year - 1, "cy": current_year}

df["year"] = df.f.str.extract(r"([^_]+)")
df["year"] = df["year"].map(mapping)
df["quarter"] = df.f.str.extract(r"_q([\d])")

df["fr_date"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (
        pd.Timestamp(year=x["year"], month=int(x["quarter"]) * 3, day=1)
        + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
    ).strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    axis=1,
)
print(df[["f", "fr_date"]])
```

Prints (for current year 2021):

```
               f   fr_date
0  l2y_q1_eps_gg  20190331
1  l2y_q2_eps_gg  20190630
2  l2y_q3_eps_gg  20190930
3  l2y_q4_eps_gg  20191231
4  l1y_q1_eps_gg  20200331
5   cy_q1_eps_gg  20210331
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df['f'].str.split('_', expand=True)], axis=1)
df
               f    0   1    2   3
0  l2y_q1_eps_gg  l2y  q1  eps  gg
1  l2y_q2_eps_gg  l2y  q2  eps  gg
2  l2y_q3_eps_gg  l2y  q3  eps  gg
3  l2y_q4_eps_gg  l2y  q4  eps  gg
4  l1y_q1_eps_gg  l1y  q1  eps  gg

df['year']=df[0].map({'l2y':'2019','l1y':'2020','cy':'2021'})
df['quarter']=df[1].str.upper()
df['fr_date'] = df['year'] + '-' + df['quarter']
df = df.drop([0,1,2,3], axis=1)
print(df)
               f  year quarter  fr_date
0  l2y_q1_eps_gg  2019      Q1  2019-Q1
1  l2y_q2_eps_gg  2019      Q2  2019-Q2
2  l2y_q3_eps_gg  2019      Q3  2019-Q3
3  l2y_q4_eps_gg  2019      Q4  2019-Q4
4  l1y_q1_eps_gg  2020      Q1  2020-Q1

df['fr_date'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{x[:4]}{x[-2:]}' for x in df['fr_date']])
df
               f  year quarter    fr_date
0  l2y_q1_eps_gg  2019      Q1 2019-01-01
1  l2y_q2_eps_gg  2019      Q2 2019-04-01
2  l2y_q3_eps_gg  2019      Q3 2019-07-01
3  l2y_q4_eps_gg  2019      Q4 2019-10-01
4  l1y_q1_eps_gg  2020      Q1 2020-01-01


df['fr_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fr_date']) +  pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
df['fr_date'] = df['fr_date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
df = df.drop(['year', 'quarter'], axis=1)
print(df)
               f   fr_date
0  l2y_q1_eps_gg  20190331
1  l2y_q2_eps_gg  20190630
2  l2y_q3_eps_gg  20190930
3  l2y_q4_eps_gg  20191231
4  l1y_q1_eps_gg  20200331
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function **change_string** and apply to column **f**. The function perform following operations:

- Create a dictionary which contains **mapping of years**
- Extract **year code** from string using **regex** and then extract **year** from that code using **dictionary**
- Extract **quarter** from string using *regex*
- Use `pd.Timestamp` to create **start of the quarter** using **year**, **month = quarter*3** and **day=1** and `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()` to compute end of the quarter.
- Finally use `strftime` to return `datetime` in **desirable** string format

```
def change_string(data):
    changes = {"cy": date.today().year, "l1y": date.today().year-1, "l2y": date.today().year-2}
    year = changes[re.findall("^l\dy", data)[0]]
    quarter = int(re.findall("_q(\d)", data)[0])
    data =  (pd.Timestamp(year=year, month =quarter * 3, day=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    return data


df = pd.DataFrame({"f":["l2y_q1_eps_gg","l2y_q2_eps_gg","l2y_q3_eps_gg","l2y_q4_eps_gg","l1y_q1_eps_gg"]})
df["fr_date"] = df.f.apply(change_string)
print(df)


               f         fr_date
    0   l2y_q1_eps_gg   20190331
    1   l2y_q2_eps_gg   20190630
    2   l2y_q3_eps_gg   20190930
    3   l2y_q4_eps_gg   20191231
    4   l1y_q1_eps_gg   20200331
```